# Scrollbar indicator displayed in the pull-to-refresh area

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Another very minor issue... :)

I've noticed that when you pull-to-refresh, the scrollbar indicator remains displayed.

In the screenshot, see the right-side of the refresh area:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tweaked this for the next build.  With every pull-to-refresh I've seen, the indicator doesn't disappear, it just stays in the top-top right corner not 50pt down like ours.

Ours is 50pt down as a resolution to technical problems with combining a refresh indicator with headers that are pinned to the top, "Activity" in this case and "Just now" in the feed.  Basically, we leave the refresh indicator fixed to the top of the screen until load completes and having the scroll indicator travel in that space feels weird.

Anyway, the tweak I've done is that when you're pulling down the indicator will never enter that white area and instead sit compressed in the grey search area.  This should look better.

Comment: Thanks. status-completed. :)